# accessing objects using dot vs brackets

Tags: javascript, object

```
  const lookup = {
    alpha : 'Adams',
    bravo : 'Boston',
    charlie : 'Chicago',
    delta : 'Denver',
    echo : 'Easy',
    foxtrot : 'Frank'
  }
  
result = lookup[val];
```

im confused as to why i am able to do `lookup[val]` but `lookup.val` would not work here.

or something like

```
const testObj = {
  12: "Namath",
  16: "Montana",
  19: "Unitas"
};
const playerNumber = 16;  
const player = testObj[playerNumber];
```

`testObj[playerNumber]` would work but `testObj.playerNumber` would not. i initally assumed because 12,16,19 were int but even changing them to strings would be the same result where dot notation dont work but bracket will.

when storing an objects property into a var are we only allowed to use bracket? is so, how come if i was to do `console.log(testObj.playerNumber)` would not work but `console.log(testObj[playerNumber])`  will?

Comment: When you run this code. You will have self descriptive error message like `lookup[echo]` then you will get `ReferenceError: echo is not defined`. From this error you will come to know that JS is looking for `echo`. Instead you should use `lookup['echo']` or `lookup.echo`

Answer (score 1):

By doing `testObj.playerNumber` you are not invoking the variable playerNumber, but rather accessing a `playerNumber` property within the `testObj` object.

Something like this:

```
const testObj = {
  playerNumber: "12"
};

testObj.playerNumber // 12
```

Comment: ohhh so dot only works if the object contains the variable whereas bracket can be used both ways?

Comment: @AndrewLin You can use brackets when the property you want to access is not a valid string for use with dots.

Comment: For example, when the property name is a number